# Is there a way to use VDPAU with the proprietary (fglrx) AMD drivers?

Tags: radeon, fglrx, steam, vdpau

I've got a relatively low-powered HTPC running Ubuntu 13.10, sporting a Radeon 6450 for graphics acceleration. I'm using the 14.6 beta of the proprietary (Catalyst/fglrx)  This machine is presently used for:

I've noticed very poor streaming performance in Steam, and tests with other devices on my network suggest that the problem is that Steam can't leverage hardware decoding on my 6450. The fglrx drivers only provide XVBA, and Steam, apparently, only supports VDPAU.

I'd prefer to stick with fglrx, but so far I haven't found any instructions on setting up VDPAU under fglrx -- though some people have suggested that XVBA could be used as a VDPAU backend. Is there any way to accomplish this, or will I have to use the open source Radeon driver?

Answer (score 0):

There is a somewhat buggy vdpau driver based on OpenGL, it can be installed via:

```
sudo apt-get install vdpauinfo libvdpau1 libvdpau-va-gl1
```

And to use it set the environment variable `VDPAU_DRIVER`:

```
VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl vdpauinfo
```

For more info see http://leodr.com/amd-fglrx-vdpau-ubuntu-14-04-hp-probook-4540s/